# Can't add migrations to database after migrating .net core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project that was created using a version of dotnet core using a project.json file. I was able to add database migrations and create a database using dotnet ef cli commands in VS Code (add migrations, update, etc.).

However, I've recently migrated the project using the dotnet migrate command, so now my project has a .csproj file. I need to add more database migrations, but when I run the cli commands, I get an error stating the project.json file could not be found.

I've looked at documentation online (and searched the web) and I can't find anything telling me what I might have missed. FWIW, here are the possible relevant packages in my .csproj file:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />

    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New versions of the tooling were released for the new `.csproj` way of doing things. You'll need to change your version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` from `1.1.0-preview4-final` to `1.0.0-msbuild3-final`.

You can see the different latest versions [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet/1.1.0-preview4-final) on Nuget.

Comment: When I change the dependency and do a restore, I get this warning: Dependency specified was Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet (>= 1.1.0-msbuild3-final) but ended up with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.1.0-preview4-final.   Oh, and I found [Julie Lerman's Blog](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/1892325.Julia_Lerman/blog) where she mentions the same thing you did.

Comment: The version is actually `1.0.0-msbuild3-final`, not `1.1.0-msbuild3-final`.  Update that and you should be good to go - I posted incorrectly at first, updated now =D.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the "dotnet ef" tools specifically you can also use the VS Powershell integrated version (Should you need the dotnet ef tools maybe steamrolla's post below can help you):

I use the following package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
```

With these references set, it is possible to use the EF-Tools (Add-Migration, Update-Database, ...) from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: The `DotNetCliToolReference` seems fine for me.

Comment: There seems to be a difference between Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools . The DotNet version is for the "dotnet ef" commands while the one without Dotnet is for the normal VS integration. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/

Comment: Correct.  If you scroll down to take a peek under `Upgrading Tooling Packages` they call it out and say if you are using the `dotnet ef` commands, you'll need to use the `.DotNet` version.

All that being said, there is actually another thing at play here in this question: the new `.csproj` way of doing things.

Comment: @Fionn I accepted the other answer since it fixed the situation I was having, but +1 as this also serves as an alternative. Thanks!